# Chromecast refuses to connect to wifi with MAC access filter turned on

Tags: mac, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, chromecast

Chromecast refuses to connect to a wifi on a router with MAC-access filter turned on, even though I have double/triple checked the MAC address and all other devices works. How can chromecast not work...? As soon as I turn access filter of it works, but I am 100% it is the correct MAC address. At least the one that is displayed on this screen in the app:

[MAC address](https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/6292171?hl=en)

Comment: Honestly, this sounds like a router problem then, if it works with the MAC filtering off AND you are positive the MAC address is correct, and UPNP is enabled (this is required for Chromecast). It is quite common to see MAC filtering used in conjunction with Chomecast, in fact it is the only way it works with AT&T U-verse Internet.

Comment: What is UPNP? It might have something to do with it maybe?

Comment: UPNP is a way an unsecure device can setup port forwarding in the router dynamically. Your router must support it and it needs to be turned on, just about every router in the last 10 years supports it. Google 'your router name upnp' for more info

Comment: But Chromecast works without access filter enabled so I guess I must have UPNP,  no? Access filter only blocks Macs,  right?

Comment: Your access list, if properly working and we are talking about a WiFi access list, allows access to specific MAC adddess(es)  to the wireless network. UPNP is required to do the proper port forwarding through the firewall and for it to be seen in the network by other devices. Google "Chromecast UPNP" for more information.

Comment: I understand,  but what I don't understand is why UPNP should be affected by the blocking of a WiFi Mac address?

Comment: sorry, I wasn't implying that... For Chromecast to work it requires a few things, assuming an original Chromecast and not 2nd generation, a working 802.11b/g network, Internet connection, devices and Chromecast is same subnet, and UPNP.

Comment: We are getting off topic here... Device works correctly with filtering off, does not work when it's on. Basic troubleshooting says the issue is in the router either incorrect configuration (your part), or a broken implementation. (router manufacturer).